# I want to change Windows authentication mode account to SQL Server authentication mode but it shows me an error which is you do not have permission

Tags: sql-server, authentication

I installed SQL Server 2008 R2 Express. But during the installation, I could not choose the both SQL Server and Windows authentication modes, and an error occurred so I did that just with Windows authentication mode.

Now, I want to change the Windows authentication mode account to SQL Server authentication mode but it shows me an error which is you do not have permission (although I am the administrator in Windows), what can I do?

Following steps are the steps that I went but I got an error:

```
Server properties > Security > Choose the option of SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode
```

and the error that I got is "Access is denied" and actually I don't have any permission to do anything!

Can you please help me?

Comment: Did you run SSMS with `run as Administrator`?  I've never seen the authentication mode selection fail during installation so there might be something else awry.  I'm curious as to what the error was.

Answer (score 0):

Login with Windows authentication and then go to security and right click logins to create a new SQL server authentication.